# Fade In & Out with Haxe & OpenFL

Tags: haxe, openfl

I am using a `For Statement` clock with Haxe and OpenFL, to create a Fade In & Fade Out effect for a Bitmap object (using `alpha` property). Do you have use other methods for that?
I am using a `For` statement instead of `Sys.sleep(0.2);` because it makes a "Loading" cursor icon and the program gets stuck.
The bitmap is called `bmp` and the timer is `tmrSplash`.

Source:

```
tmrSplash.run = function changeAlpha(): Void {
    var f: Float = 1;
    while (f <= 1 && f >= 0) {
        bmp.alpha = f;
        var a: Int = 0;
        while (a < 500000000) {
            a++;
            if (a >= 500000000) {
                a = 0;
            }
            f -= 0.0005;
            trace(f);
        }
        tmrSplash.stop();

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to fade out manually, you'll need to listen to the `ENTER_FRAME` event on the stage and change the value over time, instead of creating this infinite loop.

But I would suggest to take a look into a tween engine, like Actuate, which simplifies the syntax. You dont want to create something like this yourself, just use a library to animate properties. https://github.com/openfl/actuate

```
Actuate.tween (mySprite, 1, { alpha: 0 }); // fade out
```

Life is too short to invent another tween engine, dont waste your time on building such.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After browsing around (in the link you gave there) I'm now using this library...